# $_COOKIE does not contain expected value

Tags: php, apache, cookies, session-cookies, reverse-proxy

Our configuration (sorry, it is rather complicated):

- Apache V2.4, PHP7
- Public server with reverse proxy to private server (https://public.server is proxied to https://private.server)
- Both servers are running with SSL
- A session cookie is set for the public server domain, with cookie path 'plans'
- On the private server a PHP application running under a different path cannot see the cookie in $_COOKIE.

The directives in the public server's virtual host configuration file are:

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass "/plans" "http://private.server:8080/plans"
ProxyPassReverse "/plans" "http://private.server:8080/plans"
ProxyPass "/" "https://private.server/"
ProxyPassReverse "/" "https://private.server/"
ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain "private.server" "public.server"
ProxyPassReverseCookiePath "/" "/plans"
```

Why can't the cookie be seen?

Comment: Does it contain an unexpected value, or is not seen at all?

Comment: $_COOKIE is empty.